# How to install apache on AWS ubuntu instance?

Tags: apache-2.2, apt, amazon-web-services

I've tried a few standard Ubuntu instances on Amazon's Web Services (AWS), but I can never find the apache package using apt-get.

Thanks,
Aidan.

Comment: what is the output of apt-cache search 'apache2'? Can you append /etc/apt/sources.list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked for `apache2`?

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apache2

In general, to find a package if you don't know its exact name, use `apt-cache search`:

```
apt-cache search apache
```

So for you, I'm fairly certain what you want is:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: Only one major comment here. 
Make sure you do `apt-get update` first, or it won't find anything.

Comment: True, true, true.

Comment: I did use the search, but it found nothing. Tom's comment was the solution! All ubuntu installations I've used before already had the list of sources so I didn't expect to have to download them. Thanks everyone!